# python ctypes use pointers to get results from a function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to call a C function form my python code, the C function is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "picohttpparser.c"
#include "picohttpparser.h"

const char *path;
char buf[4096];
int pret, minor_version, i;
struct phr_header headers[100];
size_t buflen = 0, prevbuflen = 0, method_len, path_len, num_headers;
ssize_t rret;

void parse_http_request(char *request, const char *method) {
  /* parse the request */
  strncpy(buf, request, 4096);
  num_headers = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);
  phr_parse_request(buf, sizeof(buf) -1, &method, &method_len, &path, &path_len, &minor_version, headers, &num_headers, 0);
}
```

In python I am using ctypes:

```
import ctypes

_cparser = ctypes.CDLL('/tmp/serv.so')
_cparser.parse_http_request.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))


def parse(request):
    method = ctypes.c_char_p()
    _cparser.parse_http_request(ctypes.c_char_p(request.encode()), ctypes.byref(method))
    print(method)
```

method is always None, but if I compile the C code, it prints out correctly the method variable. What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you omit `ctypes.POINTER()`? Or the `.argtypes = ...` line entirely?

Comment: what is *method\_len*? Also you have `const char *method`. That means that the *method* contents is *const* and can't be modified. Something seems wrong. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mkrieger1 in both cases I still get None

Comment: @CristiFati I updated the C code, the value of method is set only later by phr_parse_request which should work? That function is taken by picohttpparser package, see here https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser/blob/master/picohttpparser.c

Comment: If `method` is being modified in your C code, it is undefined behavior due to it being `const`.  The pointer itself is also passed in by value according to the declaration so passing it in by reference is incorrect as well.  Create a reproducible example ([mcve]).